# How are points encoded in PDFs by ggplot?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, adobe, cairo

While I was trying out different shapes of `geom_point` for a figure, I noticed that the resulting PDF had very different file sizes. I investigated and found:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

testplots <- function(df, shp) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(shape = shp, alpha = 0.1)
}

testdf <- expand.grid(x = 1:40, y = 1:40, z = 1:10) 

0:25 %>% 
  walk(., ~ggsave(plot = testplots(testdf, .x), 
                  filename = paste0("./test/", .x, ".pdf")))
```

This just generates a grid of 16,000 points (with alpha transparency, which also affects file size) for each of 26 different shapes and saves each plot in an appropriately named PDF.

Then I read in the file size of each PDF and plotted the results:

```
data_frame(shp = 0:25) %>% 
  mutate(size_bytes = map_dbl(shp, 
                              ~file.size(paste0("./test/", .x, ".pdf")))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(shp, size_bytes, shape = shp)) + 
    geom_point(size = 5) + 
    scale_shape_identity()
```

[image]

My naive guess would be that circle points are encoded as vectors with something like `"draw a circle, x, y, radius"`, while squares would be `"draw a box, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4"`. So I'd guess that the more sides a polygon has, the greater the file size.

That was not the case! Circles actually always had the biggest files, while squares were the smallest. Triangles were close to squares, but then the various ornamented shapes were higher.

Anyone have an explanation?

#### P.S.

I also tried it with `ggsave(..., device = cairo_pdf)` with these results, which are similar, but not the same:

[image]